# How can I get a button to be disabled after onclick but its within another function?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, disable

I have buttons with the same onclick function.
I want the buttons to be disabled after one click. 
The onclick function needs to execute more than one function so how can I make that happen.

```
 <input type="button" class="buttons" id="button2" value="2" 
    onclick="run()" />
```

Below is code for one of the buttons, within the run function is another function running.

```
function disablebutton(button){
    this.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call the function on the different buttons.

```
        function disablebutton(buttonObject){
            buttonObject.disabled = true;
        }


        var button1 = document.getElementById('b1');
        var button2 = document.getElementById('b2');

        button1.onclick = function(){
          disablebutton(button1);
        }

         button2.onclick = function(){
          disablebutton(button2);
        }
```

OR

```
    <input type="button" class="buttons" id="button1" value="1" 
    onclick="run(this)" />  
    <input type="button" class="buttons" id="button2" value="2" 
    onclick="run(this)" /> 


    function run(button){
        button.disabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: If you have the on-click in the inline html then all you need is the JS function only, your html should be something like <button onclick="disablebutton(this)"></button>

Comment: how can i call the functions using onclick? i want the button to only be disabled afte the button has been clicked

Comment: Edited Post- also remove the onclick from the html, you dont need it with my code above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select all the buttons, and then change the disabled attribute.
You can do this by adding a class to the button, selecting them bu the class and then looping over then, disabling them all as follows:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: this disables all of the buttons after one is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can call `disablebutton()` inside `run()` function or add it after the `run()` function into `onClick()`:

```
<input type="button" class="buttons" id="button2" value="2" 
        onclick="run(); disablebutton(this)" />

// Or

<input type="button" class="buttons" id="button2" value="2" 
        onclick="run(this)" />

function run(thisButton) {
  console.log('run');
  disableButton(thisButton)
}
```

1st solution:

```js
function run() {
  console.log('run');
}

function disablebutton(button){
    console.log(button);
    button.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="buttons" id="button2" value="2" 
    onclick="run(); disablebutton(this)" />
```

2nd solution:

```js
function run(thisButton) {
  console.log('run');
  disablebutton(thisButton)
}

function disablebutton(button){
    console.log(button);
    button.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="buttons" id="button2" value="2" 
        onclick="run(this)" />
```

Comment: The run function is pointless here, it's over complicating a simple process. If using the inline html then just call the disablebutton in the inline html.